# append items multiple times to a list in a First Item First multiple order

Tags: list, append

this is what I want to accomplish:

```
alist = ['item_a1','item_a2']
blist = ['item_b1','item_b2']
final_list = []
```

I want the final list to be:

```
final_list = [['item_a1','item_a2'],['item_a1','item_a2'],['item_b1','item_b2'],['item_b1','item_b2']]
```

I know I can do it with the following clumsy codes:

```
i = 0
while i < 2:
    final_list.append(alist)
    i += 1
#then run it again with final_list.append(blist)
```

but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out my self:

```
    final_list = [alist] * 2 + [blist] * 3
```